# How make a form always on top even if the Windows 7 Flip 3D is activated

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, aero, dwm, flip3d

I'm building an app which needs display a particular form always on top (this is a customer request), so far I'm using the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the HWND_TOPMOST value, and that works fine, but when the Windows 7 Flip 3D feature is activated my app doesn't stay in top.

**Windows 7 Flip 3D**

[image]

The question is, how my form can stay on top of all the others windows even if the Windows 7 Flip 3D is activated?

Comment: Any hack you do will no doubt end up on [oldnewthing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) as an example of what not to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want to make sure your users test your uninstall program?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is a customer request because the application display real time data of an industrial system which must stay always visible to the users.

Comment: In that case killing things like Flip3D sounds like the way to go. Or running the system in a kiosk mode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I offer that options to the customer, but he reject that suggestions.

Comment: Well, the customer is always right I suppose.  ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do this some time ago using the [`DwmSetWindowAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function modyfing the [DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute with the **DWMFLIP3D_EXCLUDEABOVE** value.

Try this code

```
uses
  Winapi.DwmApi;

procedure TForm40.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pvAttribute: Integer;
begin
  pvAttribute:= DWMFLIP3D_EXCLUDEABOVE;
  if DwmCompositionEnabled then
   DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_FLIP3D_POLICY, @pvAttribute, Sizeof(Integer));
end;
```

And this is the result

[image]

Comment: Raymond Chen will hate you. <g>